# thinking sphinx automatic indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

How can I do automatic indexing for thinking sphinx or it will keep on indexing new records (added/deleted) automatically. Or I have to run

```
  rake ts:index
```

as per my needs like after 2hours or after 1 day. If I have to run, whats the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reindex periodically, use `whenever`:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby